# Controller - Returns a list yet is rendered as xml/json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, controller

I'm looking at someone's c# code and the class i'm looking at inherits from System.Web.Http.ApiController.

The method returns an IList yet when I am looking at the front-end ajax call, the data that comes back is in xml form (in the browser). The class in the IList has [Datamember] attributes on the fields so I suspect that's how it gets serialized, but why does it come back as xml when I go to the controller path directly in browser, but comes back as json data in jquery? Kinda new to this data contract thing thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the browser "ACCEPTs" when it's POSTing or GETing.

In IE, by default will accept json, but in Chrome it will by default accept XML.

Please see the [`ASP.NET Web API Tutorial`](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for more information about how this works.

Comment: I just tried in IE - it came back as a .json file. Does that seem right? And what about if I query it directly in jQuery? When I put a debugger on it in FireBug, it came back with XML wrapped around it

Comment: Yes, that is what I would expect. In the HTTP header, IE is saying it ACCEPTs `*.*` content types by default, but no supported content types are explicitly listed, so it returns the default. Where in Chrome/FireBug `application/xml` is specified before `*.*`, so it will return that.